# Meaning of "to become a staple" and other phrases with staple

Tags: phrases

What does staple mean in phrases?
Examples:

- Similarly, the C programming language became a staple of the computer science classroom.
- When did the potato become a staple food?
- http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/staple

Is it roughly something like "main" or "basic"?

Comment: This can be answered by looking it up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Staple* can be both a noun and an adjective. In these two sentences, it's a noun, unlike *main* and *basic*, which are adjectives. In the case of the first sentence, it's 'the thing chiefly “dealt in”; the principal object of employment, thought, or discourse. Sometimes . . . used for: The chief component element, the "substance", "bulk".' In the case of the second, it's 'a principal industrial product of a country, town, or district; occasionally the commodity principally dealt in by a person or class of persons. Also, the principal or basic food on which a community lives.' Both definitions are from the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: Likewise the New Oxford English Dictionary: a main or important element of something, esp. of a diet (staple^2 definition 1).